# Scatterplot matrix in R on iris dataset not very clear

Tags: correlation, dataset, matrix, scatterplot

I am tryin to generate some scatterplot matrices in R using IRIS dataset. First I do this:

```
data(iris)
cor(iris[,1:4])
```

This gives a nice symmteric matrix:

```
             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1175698    0.8717538   0.8179411
Sepal.Width    -0.1175698   1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
Petal.Length    0.8717538  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
Petal.Width     0.8179411  -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```

Then I do:

```
pairs(iris[,1:4])
```

How come the resulting diagram does not have a symmetric nature to it? The plots on either side of the diagonal are not same, why not? The correlations are same on either side of the diagonal, so how come the plots are not same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symmetry that's required is that for corresponding elements, the same picture results when interchanging x and y.

The pairs plot is symmetric in the required way. If you flip the $i,j$ sub-plot about its own diagonal (which is what swapping x and y does), you get the corresponding image from the $j,i$ sub-plot.

For example, here's the lower 2x2 portion of the plot your code generates (colored red below the diagonal to make the necessary comparison easier), plus the transformations needed to show they're the same in the way they're supposed to be. [Flipping about the diagonal isn't directly available, but I've achieved it in two steps by rotation and flipping about a vertical axis (a 'horizontal flip' in the software I used to flip the image)]:

[image]